# How I can upload file to folder in bucket in S3 using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, localstack

I have local S3 and want to upload some files into folders in mu bucket.
For example:

> - my_bucket
>   - folder1
>   - folder2

I have to upload file **file1.json** to **folder1** and **file1.json** to **folder1**
I try do this like:

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')

with open("path_to_file","rb") as data:
    bucket.put_object(Key='folder1/file1.json', Body=data)
```

But it don't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error? Is the file misplaced?

Comment: @OferSadan - cause folder is empty. Code haven't errors.

Comment: Your code works for me @AntonHauff... Check permits in S3 and make sure you are checking for uploads in the correct way.

Comment: What is the error? Are you using `localstack` as you have tagged it? If yes, you need to initialise your resource as `s3 = boto3.resource("s3", endpoint_url="http://localhost:4566")`

Answer (score 1):

An even easier method would be:

```py
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')
bucket.upload_file('filename_on_local_disk.json', 'folder1/file.json')
```